# How to uninstall Atollic TrueSTUDIO for STM32 (Linux)?

Tags: linux, debian, stm32, truestudio

I've downloaded and installed the ATOLLIC TRUESTUDIO FOR STM32 on my computer (Linux) from the STM32 official website. Unfortunately, it is not working appropriately. It keeps crashing all the time. Hence, I want to uninstall it, although I didn't find any relevant document that gives some guidelines on how to uninstall this IDe. If anyone knows the procedure, please help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For those who may be unaware, this question is [on-topic for StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), as it relates to installation/removal of a software suite that is unique to software development.  This is not an assessment of the quality.... it certainly would have benefited from knowing the computer architecture, Linux distribution, and Atollic TrueStudio version, as well as how it was installed in the first place.  But it is not a question about general-use Linux software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution! First, we need to go to /opt/ folder (with the help of cd /opt/). Then we can see that there will be an Atollic folder (so we need to cd into that folder). Inside the Atollic folder, there will be a file called uninstall.sh. We need to run this shell script file.

```
cd /opt/Atollic....
sudo sh uninstall.sh
```